# psql: id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY not starting with 1?

Tags: postgresql, bulkcopy, serialization

This is something I don't understand, can somebody explain?

I create a table

```
CREATE TABLE cali (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ALK_from char,
    ALK_to char,
    AND_from char,
    AND_to char);
```

Then I simply try to insert some data from a csv file like so

```
\COPY cali FROM '/home/.../data/output/id_cali.csv' (FORMAT CSV);
```

Which gives me this Error:

```
ERROR:  value "4372840000" is out of range for type integer
CONTEXT:  COPY cali, line 1, column id: "4372840000"
```

I know that 4372840000 results in an integer overflow. That is why I'm trying to insert the values as chars in the first place.

But my understanding is that `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` is some sort of auto increment why is the value 4372840000 used for the column `id`?

The file looks like this

```
4372840012,4372840013,13,14,
4372840014,4372840014,15,15,
```

Answer (score 6):

The table should be

```
create table cali (
    id serial primary key,
    alk_from bigint,
    alk_to bigint,
    and_from int,
    and_to int
);
```

And do

```
\COPY cali (alk_from, alk_to, and_from, and_to) 
FROM '/home/.../data/output/id_cali.csv' 
(FORMAT CSV);
```

So that it knows to not insert into the id serial column. The serial type is not a true type. [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases)
>
> Thus, we have created an integer column and arranged for its default values to be assigned from a sequence generator

Comment: I see. So id will be auto populated by the first column if you don't specify the column names with `\copy`?

Comment: copy will of course start putting values into the columns in the order they are, unless you tell it otherwise. Serial is no special value, it's just a way to say "this is an int column, please create a sequence and put the default value to be taken from there."

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table with same statement but subsequently execute following statement - basically you are altering the data-type for your id column.

`alter table cali alter column id type bigint;`

Comment: This will not result in correct data in the database by itself in this case.

Answer (score -3):

> and for your problem you should take columns datatype as bigint so you
>   will not get this error.
>
> you can not insert value in primary key column which is
>   autoincremented

CREATE TABLE cali (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        ALK_from bigint,
        ALK_to bigint,
        AND_from bigint,
        AND_to bigint);